# Creating bookmarks in QGIS from CSV file containing coordinates?

Tags: qgis, csv, bookmarks

Does QGIS have the functionality to input a CSV file containing coordinates & scale of the map, and then output bookmarks for different coordinates?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Could you click 'edit' and give some more information? What kind of input file do you envision - a text file? And do you want it to create a QGIS XML bookmark?

Comment: For example, a csv file containing coordinates of different places and I want to bookmark these places. The format of the bookmark does not matter, as long as I can easily reference them in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this feature is available via the QGIS UI, however you could create a console python script or plugin that reads xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax coordinates from a .csv (reading data (coordinates) from .csv using python you should find some examples of this by doing a web search like "read csv data or attributes python") and adds the book mark record to the users tbl_bookmarks sqlite table.  For more info on how to write the coordinates to the table see tutorial below:

[Map Bookmarks: QGIS Python Programming CookBook](https://www.gislounge.com/map-bookmarks-qgis-python-programming-cookbook/)